# Wordpress custom post type single post preview for pending status

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created custom post type and created the post in a front custom form using logged in user and set status 'pending'. Now I want to show my created post preview like the published post.

I have hit URL like admin
http://localhost/project/?post_type=deals&p=3305

but it is working for admin, not for author user.

In Another way, we can say that how to show pending custom post for author only for preview.

Please help

Comment: It sounds like you have an issue with your permissions/capabilities from when you registered the custom post type.

Comment: in the cpt properties what is 'publicly_queryable' set to? if not set define it to true with 'publicly_queryable' => true,

Comment: 'publicly_queryable' => true,
its already added.